# Trying to load in keras and tensorflow, I am still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator' in my Anaconda Enviornment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

This is the full error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-7a2fd3f04482>", line 24, in <module>
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegrssor
ImportError: cannot import name 'GradientBoostingRegrssor' from 'sklearn.ensemble' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

I upgraded the versions of the keras and tensorflow in the Anaconda Command Prompt here are the current versions

[image: current versions]

I have also tried restarting my kernel

here is the original code

```
import keras
import tensorflow as ts
from pylab import mpl, plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Dense
from keras.ptimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.wrapper.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
```

any help resolving this issue would be appreciated

Comment: Where is this first error coming from? Could you please fix that first, then repost if you still have an issue? It is a simple typo `from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegrssor` should be `from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just simple type as commented by @merv

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
```

or

```
sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor
```